# What are the changes I should make and why in order to solve this problem?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

Question - Find the number of ways that a given integer,X, can be expressed as the sum of the Nth powers of unique, natural numbers.

I am trying to solve the following problem in hackerrank
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-power-sum/problem
and even though I have reached the condition I am still not getting an updated answer.

```
// Complete the powerSum function below.
int powers(int X,int N,int s)
 {
   //cout<<X<<" "<<s<<endl;
   if(s<=0||X<0)
    return 0;
  if(X==0)
      return 1;
  return powers(X-pow(s,N),N,s-1)+powers(X,N,s-1);
 }
int powerSum(int X, int N) {
   int s = (int)(sqrt(X));
   int num=1;   
  return powers(X,N,s);
}
```

What I am trying to do in this code is that when my X reaches 0 that is when the condition satisfies and it should return 1 and I printed all the values of X in the code some of which were 0. So, my query is that if the value of X is reaching 0 and it is returning 1 then what is the mistake in my code that it is not returning the proper value.
E.g - X=10
      N=2
 Correct output:-1
 My output:-0

Comment: Please include the problem statement in your question, so that the question is self-contained.

Comment: also please always add the language tag

Comment: what is the problem with your current solution? What is the expected output and what is the actual output you are getting? What does "I am not getting an updated answer" mean?

Comment: Is my description clearer now?

Comment: Yes, clearer, but still difficult to parse. (maybe it's just me, I am tired). You need to make your code more readable. What is `s`? what is `powers` supposed to return? A reader should be able to quickly figure out these things. Unfortunately these competitions only care about result and speed. They leave out one of the most important skill of a programmer: code quality. Properly name your variables, Properly name your functions. Document what your functions do. Document your parameters.

Comment: At a first glance `sqrt(N)` looks wrong. The problem is about powers of N, not square roots so `sqrt` is suspicious.

Comment: For the first  comment definitely I will take care next time before posting questions and for the second I don't think it should matter as the range of `N` is from 2 to 10 so if I set it to  `sqrt(X)` then I am making sure that all the numbers are covered and even if the number is larger than `X` then it wouldn't matter as I am returning 0.

Comment: Maybe you think there is only one way to solve the problem so you think that everybody understands what you are trying to do in `powers`. My solution to the problem is completely different and I cannot understand what you are trying to do. **You don't explain the solution you are trying to implement**. And your code is completely undocumented. As I've said, properly naming your variables and documenting your code is a very powerful tool.

Comment: ok, I finally understood what you are trying to do. But I had to wrap my head around it. Next time please help us help you.

Comment: I am so sorry for the inconvenience. I would take due care next time and also thank you for giving your time for my problem.

Comment: [had fun implementing a totally different algorithm](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be5fa01a3d95980f)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull `if(X==0)` first. If you have a solution (`X == 0`) but `s` reached `0` you don't count it.

```
int powers(int X, int N, int s)
{
    if (X == 0)
        return 1;
    if (s <= 0 || X < 0)
        return 0;
    return powers(X - pow(s, N), N, s - 1) + powers(X, N, s - 1);
}
```

Comment: Note, this takes O(2^X) time, so is... very slow.  This problem can be solved in O(N^2) time.

Comment: This is help with his solution. I am not going to do the challenge for him.